# Jbehave scenario with metafilter and table of parameters

Tags: filter, parameters, meta, jbehave

I'm facing an issue with Jbehave, and I don't know what am I doing wrong

I have some scenarios with tables of parameters, and I have to add a meta to these scenarios, when I do that, the test stop running, if I remove the table or remove the meta, everything works fine, but when I put both, the scenario doesn't run

My scenario is the following:

```
Scenario: The user do something
Meta: @meta
Given <USER1> exists
When user <USER1> do <ACTION>
Then I verify if <ACTION> has been perfomed

Examples:
|USER1|ACTION|
|userA|actionA|
|userB|actionB|
|userC|actionC|
```

if I let only:

```
Scenario: The user do something
Meta: @meta
Given <USER1> exists
When user <USER1> do <ACTION>
Then I verify if <ACTION> has been perfomed
```

or only:

```
Scenario: The user do something
Given <USER1> exists
When user <USER1> do <ACTION>
Then I verify if <ACTION> has been perfomed

Examples:
|USER1|ACTION|
|userA|actionA|
|userB|actionB|
|userC|actionC|
```

it works perfectly, but if I add both meta and the examples table, the scenario isn't executed.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

[JBehave Documentation](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/grammar.html)

This page implies that the Meta tag should be BEFORE the scenario.  That is the only thing that stood-out to me.  Why it would only detect it as a problem if the Examples were included hints that it might not be the answer.  Worth a try.

Comment: I always used it after scenario, how it would be?

`Meta: @meta
Scenario: The user do something
Given ...`

is it?

Comment: [Meta Info](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-info.html) shows it being done both ways, so it might not be the problem.  and [Meta Filtering](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html) shows it being used **inside** an Examples table.

Comment: so, to create a metafilter for this scenario, I need to create it inside the examples table, not the scenario, correct? thanks for the help!